# Flutter - Retrieve coordinates from user's current position

Tags: android, flutter, geolocator

I'm a newbie and I'm on a Flutter project where I'm trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude from user's current position.

I have this code:

```
class ProductHorizontalListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductHorizontalListItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.coreTagKey,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final Function? onTap;
  final String coreTagKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('***Tag*** $coreTagKey${PsConst.HERO_TAG__IMAGE}');
    final PsValueHolder valueHolder =
    Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

final double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
      0,
      0,
      double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lat.toString()),
      double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lng.toString()),
    );

    const double km = 1.60;
    final double distance = double.parse(valueHolder.mile.toString());
    final double total = distance * km;

    return InkWell(
        onTap: onTap as void Function()?,
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: PsDimens.space4, right: PsDimens.space4,
                bottom: PsDimens.space12),
            child: Text(
                '${distanceInMeters}' '${product.itemLocation!.name}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3
                )))

        );
  }
}
```

Instead of zero I need to pass the right latitude and longitude of the user.

I tried with Geolocator plugin but I had no luck probably due to my lack of knowledge.

Can some body help about how to implement correctly?

Thank you so much.

### UPDATE

I tried to implement the Geolocator.getCurrentPosition and this is the code:

```
class ProductHorizontalListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductHorizontalListItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.coreTagKey,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final Function? onTap;
  final String coreTagKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('***Tag*** $coreTagKey${PsConst.HERO_TAG__IMAGE}');
    final PsValueHolder valueHolder =
    Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
      bool serviceEnabled;
      LocationPermission permission;

      // Test if location services are enabled.
      serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        // Location services are not enabled don't continue
        // accessing the position and request users of the
        // App to enable the location services.
        return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
      }

      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
          // requesting permissions again (this is also where
          // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
          // returned true. According to Android guidelines
          // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
          return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
        }
      }

      if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
        return Future.error(
            'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
      }

      // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
      // continue accessing the position of the device.
      return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    }
    print(_determinePosition);

    return InkWell(
        onTap: onTap as void Function()?,
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: PsDimens.space4, right: PsDimens.space4,
                bottom: PsDimens.space12),
            child: Text(
                '${_determinePosition()}' '${product.itemLocation!.name}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3
                )))

        );
  }
}
```

But on print the console give me `closure: () => future<position>`

Comment: The Geolocator plugin is well documented ! you should take your time to understand how it works ;) Finally, you can still get the example app of the package to check how it works :)

Comment: @FPerroch you're right and I ask apologize to all Stackoverflow's community for the newbie question. Trust me, I tried very much time but without success. So I ask some help :(

Comment: Did you try to get the example app of package work ?

Comment: Check out the example on pub.dev from geolactor. You can basicly copy paste the function. Call the function, check if the position is not null and use the values from it

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I tried but I have the result "Closure: () => Future<Position>"

Comment: @FPerroch I tried but I have the result "Closure: () => Future<Position>"

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I updated my question and you can see the code below "UPDATE"

Comment: You just print the function. You have to call it like this Position? position = await _determinePosition();

Comment: @OzanTaskiran You're right, but I called it like you said but I have now
'Future<Widget> Function(BuildContext)') isn't a valid override of 'StatelessWidget.build'